# Apart from ANT is there any tool which automate deployment

Tags: deployment, ant

Apart from ANT is there any tool which can be used for deployment

Comment: There are some paid apps available which will do this work for you

Answer (score 2):

I ain't promoting any tool, but i have liked using 
[Gearset](https://gearset.com/) for automating deployments , its fast and reliable.

Apart from that you can use something free like jenkins that automatically makes build for you. More info here. (It still uses ant but is handy and customisable) 
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/setting-up-jenkins-for-force-com-continuous-integration.html

You can also try [Salesforce Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataDeploy.php) to deploy, its good and its like Swiss army knife.

Comment: Doesn't Jenkins just use ANT?

Comment: I kinda have assumption that all deployment tools are build using ant, even standard SF changesets.

Comment: What makes you think that change sets use ANT?

Comment: I have downloaded a changeset using workbench and the config files inside made me believe its ant. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: What command did you use in workbench?

Comment: I haven't used change sets in a long time, but from everything I've read about the metadata and tooling apis, there's no way to send a metadata package to an org and have it appear in the "inbound changesets" section

Comment: You could also add workbench to the list of tools that can do deployments, and as far as I know they do deployments through the metadata api directly with cURL (without using ANT).

Comment: Just wrote steps with pics to show how to download changeset via workbench.
No promotion though.
https://itsrainingcloud.blogspot.in/2016/08/how-to-download-salesforce-chang.html

Comment: Cool. blogspot's blocked here, so I'll have to check it out later.

Comment: That is not a change set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43476/discussion-between-pranay-jaiswal-and-martin).